# Running Xcode Projects

Tags: server

Is it possible to run a Xcode project on a RPi?

I have a simple server written in objective c on Xcode that I'd like to put on a RPi but I haven't found any way to do it or even if it's possible.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No it is not possible to run Xcode on the raspberry Pi as Xcode is proprietary to apple products such as the MacBook and Mac Pro.

Even if you are able to compile your objective c code,you will be very limited with what you can do as attempting to test it on a phone or upload it to the App Store or even run an iOS emulator is impossible/unlawful without a mac.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to compile your Objective C code on Linux. You'll need to install the compiler yourself and then run it on your code.  You can see here for instructions on how to install the compilers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437361/how-to-objective-c-in-linux

The only way this would be a problem is if your Objective C code is intertwined with Mac-specific system libraries. Hopefully you didn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. You can install [Swish](https://github.com/thomaspaulmann/Swish) to build Swift projects remotely.

Swish is a simple script for remote building your Swift projects on a Linux machine. Why is that so cool? You can develop in Xcode on macOS and can use an External Build System to deploy your code on Linux.

The next chapters are all about integrating Swish in Xcode and describes how to build Swift projects on a remote machine right outta Xcode. It targets the early adopters of Server-Side Swift and should minimize the gap between macOS and Linux. It's work in progress, so please report any issues that you're running in.

<sup>[1]</sup> [Compile Swift for Raspberry Pi by XCode](https://swiftreviewer.com/2018/12/25/compile-swift-for-raspberry-pi-by-xcode/)

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer only with a link (link-only answer); explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed or you risk to get down votes.